# Google Sheets onEdit trigger for specific column

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have the code below that seems to work great for what I need, but I only want it to run when an edit is made to a specific column within the sheet. I want to run it only when Column 16 is edited. I have the following code:

```
SHEET_NAME = "Current Ready Service";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A7:BQ";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 67, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 68, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
{column: 69, ascending: true},
{column: 6, ascending: true},
{column: 16, ascending: true},
{column: 15, ascending: true},
{column: 14, ascending: true}
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Only run on a specific column

```
function onEdit(e) {
  multiSortColumns(e);
}
function multiSortColumns(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == specific column) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
    range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
    ss.toast('Sort complete.');
  }
}
```